# How to pivot image with CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am trying to pivot an image around a specific point.  I have been following the example here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp

However,  i am running into some issues when implementing this in a javascript directive. my code for this directive is as follows:

```
angular.module('GbTestApp').directive('rotate', function () {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.degrees, function (rotateDegrees) {
            console.log(rotateDegrees);
            var r = 'rotate(' + rotateDegrees + 'deg)';
            element.css({
                '-moz-transform': r,
                '-moz-transform-origin': 50% 50%,
                '-webkit-transform': r,
                '-webkit-transform-origin': 50% 50%,
                '-o-transform': r,
                '-o-transform-origin': 50% 50%,
                '-ms-transform': r,
                '-ms-transform-origin': 50% 50%,
                'transform-origin': 50% 50%
            });
        });
    }
    }
});
```

This function work when I take out all of the transform origin parts,  so I believe that this is just a formatting error of some kind that I am just not seeing.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried to put the value of your json between quotes ('50% 50%') ?

Comment: You should have a look on CSS `Keyframes` to animate this only with CSS.

Comment: I don't really understand why you try out to make a directive that apply some CSS. In my head this is called a CSS class.

Comment: It turns out that i need to add quotes,  so thanks Mehdi Brillaud.   As well,  Im relatively new to all this CSS and javascript stuff,  so i wasn't sure how to make changes to CSS classes based on input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap `50% 50%` in quotes; ie `"50% 50%"`.

However, I'd advocate moving all of the `transform-origin` styles to a stylesheet and adding them to your image via class. Example:

```
img.turnable {
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

Then apply `class="turnable"` to the element, and all you'll have to update to turn it is the rotation.